# We have broadcast solution in Corda Enterprise?

Tags: corda

Does the Corda Enterprise have an Information Broadcast solution?

If it does not currently exist, will it be possible in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is, of course you can perform "information broadcast" and it can do so in exactly the same way that other DLT platforms do. In fact, it makes no sense that you *can't* broadcast with Corda!

This question comes up a lot, probably because there is some marketing material which says that Corda messaging happens on a peer to peer basis and that "there is no broadcast". What this actually means is that there is no gossiping of transactions with Corda. This is a good thing because it means peers have fine-grained control over which other peers can see their transactions.

To send a message to a peer on a network, you must know where the recipient can be reached. As such DLT/blockchain platforms maintain a list of peers. Platforms like Bitcoin, have a list of peers bundled with the software to bootstrap the network. This list can grow as more peers are discovered. With Corda, this is currently done through the network map service. Corda nodes can query their local cache of the network map to get a list of peers on the network.

If you want to broadcast a message to all peers on the network or a sub-set of peers on the network then it follows that you can iterate through the set of peers that you which to send a message to and send them the message. Easy. Note there is no gossiping here. It's simply just a bunch of unicast messages. You can do this asynchronously, as well.

It is also possible to facilitate gossiping of messages with Corda. In [section 12 of the technical white paper](https://www.corda.net/content/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf), there is a concept mentioned called data distribution groups or clubs. You can think of a club as a directed minimum spanning tree of nodes on a network, which might look something like this:

[image]

As such, a node can start a club, then invite others to it, and so on. Members of the club can send a message to the club and it will be forwarded on to all the others. Referring to the image above, if node one publishes a message to the club, then all the other nodes will receive it.

I've implemented a prototype of this [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3763/files). It's a feature that we plan to roll out in the near future.

Comment: ok, I got it !
I really liked the idea of groups or clubs!
I have a doubt.
I noticed that Corda Enterprise does not have DR, if I lose the whole database of a node, how can I restore this node? How can I restore all my lost database?

Comment: There is DR - you can currently run a node in a Hot/Cold HA configuration. You should probably back up the node database, just like you back up any other data, as relying on your counter-parties to do your backups is not a sensible idea! :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably worth noting that most networks don't default to broadcasting or multicasting because it makes them a lot slower (if you look into the original history of the Internet, for example, you'll see that multicast didn't exist).

Broadcast platforms have a lot of problems in that senders typically don't know if the recipients have received those messages or not, so it's not at all unusual to find that when some systems talk about "broadcasting" they actually do multiple unicasts instead.

The Corda approach means that there's guaranteed delivery of the messages sent to all the relevant parties.  As a point of comparison, even though Wi-Fi networks support multicast messages at L2, most access points will prefer to convert L3 (IP level) multicasts into a series of point-to-point L2 messages as these will be delivered reliably (the receiver ACKs the messages).

It's not that hard to build a gossipy sort of design on top of Corda's messaging.  We did this for project Ubin phase 2a in 2017.